# Jupyter bash not saving environmental variable definition

Tags: bash, environment-variables, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I'm trying to assign a new value to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, but the change does not seem to take effect inside my Jupyter notebook.

[image]

So how can I effectively change this value inside Jupyter?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the proper way to set this was:

```py
%env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/
```